# XXXX!.Type does not have a memeber YYYY

Tags: swift, option-type

```
class SomeClass {
    class var category: Int {
        return 1class SomeClass {
    class var category: Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    var someClass: SomeClass!

    init() {
        someClass = SomeClass()
    }
}

var a = AnotherClass()
println("\(a.someClass.dynamicType.category)")   // error: SomeClass!.Type does not have a member named category
println("\(SomeClass.category)")  // print 1
```

of course I can use SomeClass.category,
here is just an example to show the problem.
when I don't know the exact type of a.someClass, inheritance for example, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
println("\(a.someClass!.dynamicType.category)")
```

Unlike normal member access, `.dynamicType` does not implicitly unwrap the `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`

In your case, `a.someClass` is `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<SomeClass>`, and `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>` has no `.category` static member.

So, you have to manually unwrap it with `a.someClass!`

Comment: thx. tried it, not working, so put a question here. but now it magically works